# Removing element from list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
raw_data = raw_data = [{'type': 'message',
  'subtype': 'bot_message',
  'text': "This content can't be displayed.",
  'ts': '1650899428.077709',
  'username': 'Typeform',
  'icons': {'image_01': 'www.example.com/foo.png'},
  'bot_id': 'BPD1K2SJW',
  'app_id': 'AD6SC3RT6',
  'blocks': [{'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'Smd',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': 'You have a new response.',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': '6YaLt',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Where did you first hear about us?*\nOnline Search',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'w3o',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Direction: *\nNorth',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'PTQ',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Location? *\nNew York',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'JCfSP',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*What can we do better? *\nTo Nothing',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'aATCO',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*What is your age? *\n32',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'FbB',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Can we speak with you?*\nNo',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'GR+=',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Order Number:*\n123456',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'actions',
    'block_id': '71Q',
    'elements': [{'type': 'button',
      'action_id': '+hZp',
      'text': {'type': 'plain_text', 'text': 'View results', 'emoji': True},
      'url': 'www.example.com/form/abcd/results'}]},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'RJOA',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn', 'text': ' ', 'verbatim': False}}]},

 {'type': 'message',
  'subtype': 'channel_join',
  'ts': '1650897264.344889',
  'user': 'U03CTDZ4MA6',
  'text': '<@T19CTAB4MA6> has joined the channel',
  'inviter': 'T049HGBCW'},
            
{'type': 'message',
  'subtype': 'bot_message',
  'text': "This content can't be displayed.",
  'ts': '1650899428.077709',
  'username': 'Typeform',
  'icons': {'image_01': 'www.example.com/foo.png'},
  'bot_id': 'BPD1K2SJW',
  'app_id': 'AD6SC3RT6',
  'blocks': [{'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'Smd',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': 'You have a new response.',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': '6YaLt',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Where did you first hear about us?*\nOnline Search',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'w3o',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Direction: *\nNorth',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'PTQ',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Location? *\nNew York',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'JCfSP',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*What can we do better? *\nTo Nothing',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'aATCO',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*What is your age? *\n32',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'FbB',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Can we speak with you?*\nNo',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'GR+=',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
     'text': '*Order Number:*\n123456',
     'verbatim': False}},
   {'type': 'actions',
    'block_id': '71Q',
    'elements': [{'type': 'button',
      'action_id': '+hZp',
      'text': {'type': 'plain_text', 'text': 'View results', 'emoji': True},
      'url': 'www.example.com/form/abcd/results'}]},
   {'type': 'section',
    'block_id': 'RJOA',
    'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn', 'text': ' ', 'verbatim': False}}]}
           
]
```

I would like to be able to drop the following from this list:

```
 {'type': 'message',
  'subtype': 'channel_join',
  'ts': '1650897264.344889',
  'user': 'U03CTDZ4MA6',
  'text': '<@T19CTAB4MA6> has joined the channel',
  'inviter': 'T049HGBCW'},
```

I do ***not*** want to drop by index because this block can be anywhere is the list (which contains hundreds of elements).

I'm using the following:

```
trimmed = [[elem for elem in dat['type'] if elem['type']['subtype'] != 'channel_join'] for dat in raw_data]
```

Which gives me a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried writing some normal `for` loops instead of a list comprehension you don't understand?

Comment: Do you mean you want to drop any dict that contains any of these key-value pairs?

Comment: @enke - yes, I want to remove any dict from the list that contains those key-value pairs.

Comment: Wouldn't the following be a bit more compact?  `filtered_data = [elem for elem in raw_data if not (elem.get('type') == 'message' and elem.get('subtype') == 'channel_join')]`

Comment: "Downvoted on a full reproducible example? Really?" Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. This question is still missing a lot of relevant information. For example, it should have a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, and an explanation of the intended logic. Where you say "I would like to be able to drop the following from this list" - *what is the rule that tells you* that this is what should be dropped, and nothing else? It would also be useful to indent and format the `raw_data` neatly and consistently, to highlight the structure.

Comment: Also, it is important to [try to solve the problem yourself first](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), which starts with [reading and understanding](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) the error message. It says "string indices must be integers". Okay - do you know what this means? Were you able to figure out what string is being indexed into when the error occurs? Were you able to figure out what non-integer was being used? Were you able to figure out why this happens, and at what point in the process it happens?

Comment: (Hint: where the outer list comprehension says `for dat in raw_data`, what do you expect each `dat` value to look like? Where the inner comprehension says `elem for elem in dat['type']`, what will `dat['type']` look like? What will `elem` end up as? Does `elem['type']['subtype']` make sense? Why? What do you expect will happen?)

Comment: (Hint: what is the level of nesting of the thing you want to remove?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the filter() function:

```
def myfilter(item):
    if item.get('type') == 'message' and item.get('subtype') == 'channel_join':
        return False
    return True

filtered_data = list(filter(myfilter, raw_data))
print(len(raw_data))
print(len(filtered_data))
```

Or as a list comp:

```
filtered_data = [x for x in raw_data if myfilter(x)]
```

The main problem in your code is this: `elem['type']['subtype']`

elem['type'] is the string "message", and that string has no element named 'subtype'

Comment: There is no reason why this can't be done just the same with a list comprehension. The problem is with the internal logic, not with the general approach.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine if you want to use list comprehension.

```
drop =  {'type': 'message',
  'subtype': 'channel_join',
  'ts': '1650897264.344889',
  'user': 'U03CTDZ4MA6',
  'text': '<@T19CTAB4MA6> has joined the channel',
  'inviter': 'T049HGBCW'}
  
  
data = [x for x in raw_data if(x!=drop)]

print(data)
```